Не загружает Linux
не загружается виртуалка с linux
Пишет cant access tty job control off
Фото экрана во вложение
Очень плохо понимаю в линукс, помогите пожалуйста, произошло после выключения света при работающем сервере


проблемы у вас с блочным устройством, а не с тем, что вы написали.

Можете подсказать, что можно сделать

Виртуалка с zfs и посыпавшимся диском и фотографией tty вместо скриншота окна? Что-то здесь нечисто

Можете подсказать, что можно сделать - обычно заменяют на новое.

Какого окна? Я просто не понимаю

Скорее всего это не виртуалка.

Жесткий диск полетел?
